# why incremental count starting with 0 instead of 1?

Tags: java, aspectj

I am using aspectJ with java to run some codes. I want to get an incremental count of a method call. So I used `count++` in my code. When I get the result of my test codes, it shows

```
0
1  
2
```

I was expecting to see `1` and `2`, but not the `0`. any idea why I am getting a `0` first. How can I stop that `0` from appearing?

Here's my code:

```
public aspect TrackMoneyOwed{
    private static int calcCallCount=0;

    pointcut calculatePriceCall():
       call(* *.calculatePrice());

    after(): calculatePriceCall(){   
        System.out.println(calcCallCount++);       
    }
}
```

I am really new in coding. So I will really appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: where is the `some codes`?

Comment: Because you're displaying before incrementing, maybe? Hard to say without ze codez ...

Comment: public aspect TrackMoneyOwed{
    private static int calcCallCount=0;
    /*private double licenseFee; */

    pointcut calculatePriceCall():
       call(* *.calculatePrice());

    after(): calculatePriceCall(){   
       
        System.out.println(calcCallCount++);       
    }
}

Comment: I edited my post with codes.

Comment: yeah just did that AntonH. sorry. pretty new to stackOverflow too. so making stupid mistakes.

Comment: `System.out.println(calcCallCount++);`. This line basically prints the value of `calcCallCount` before incrementing it; it's called post-increment. You would have to pre-increment: `System.out.println(++calcCallCount);`.

Comment: I tried ++calcCallCount before even posting the question here. it did not work.

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work? What did it print?

Comment: it showed 1 2 3. but I only had two methods that got called. so it should have shown a count of 1 2. it's doing an extra count.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(calcCallCount++);
```

prints `calCallCount` first and then increments it. Use `System.out.println(++calcCallCount);` to first increment and then print.

The difference between `i++` and `++i` is that `i++` increments `i` once it was read, and `++i` increments right before being read. `i++` is called post-incrementation and `++i` is called pre-incrementation.